# Failure to Import Curl in Postman - optionless arguments found

Tags: api, curl, postman

I've tried pasting a raw curl into Postman using File >> Import >> Paste Raw Text. However, I get the error: Error while importing Curl: 2 option-less arguments found. Only one is supported (the URL). Below is the curl.

```
curl 'https://example.com/api/dataexport/user_token' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.boostr.dataexport' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"auth":{"email”:”example@example.com”,”password”:”example”}}’ --compressed
```

Answer (score 5):

**--compressed**  not supported ***remove it from the end***

and use the "Copy as CURL (bash)" option

[reference](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5735)

Answer (score 2):

The quotation marks in the value for `--data-binary` need to be replaced from `”` (typographic quotes) to `"` (ASCII quotes).

Try importing this:

```
curl 'https://example.com/api/dataexport/user_token' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.boostr.dataexport' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"auth":{"email":"example@example.com","password":"example"}}' --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

When Copying a request from Chrome Dev Tools, use the "Copy as CURL (bash)" option to ensure that Postman will accept the format.